# get the host and alias in PHP

Tags: php, apache

In PHP if I use **$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']** I get the proper *host.com* 
However, I configured apache to use an alias but HTTP_POST doesn't return that alias. **host.com/alias/** index.php
What can I use in PHP to also get the alias?

**EDIT**

In apache you can specify an alias such as 
`http://localhost/myapp redirects` to a specific directory such as `C:/myapp`

Now within my php application I needed a way to get the full path to my application so I can generate an absolute url to a file in my application. `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` only provided the domain **(localhost)** and not the alias **(myapp)** which is part of the url.

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump($_SERVER)` and see if you find the correct information in another variable?

Comment: Whatever problem you have, I'm not really sure if you asked the right question. Try to add some more information so it becomes more clear what you're talking about. For example if you add some example code you run into a problem with, this might help to describe your question better. Also add the output of `var_dump($_SERVER)` to your question, that's a good suggestion by @MathieuImbert.

Comment: did u try $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! The alias is present in $_SERVER['CONTEXT_PREFIX'].